# MongoDB EC2 C# Upload Issues - Missing Key?

Tags: c#, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Looking for help on this one.

I'm currently building a C# interface that should ideally upload JSON documents into a MongoDB database stored on an EC2 Server.

So far, I've been able to access the instance of Mongo on the EC2 server using PuTTY and the resulting console line interface, but am unable to do this in C#. Each time I've been getting the same error:

```
Additional information: Unable to connect to server bitnami@ec2-54-174-43-69.compute-1.amazonaws.com:22: A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup.
```

The code I am using is below (username, password, and database name modified for privacy):

```
            // Create a metadataObj for upload.
            MetadataTemplate metaUpload = createMetadataObj();

            // Upload to MongoDB
            var connectionString = "mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@bitnami@ec2-54-174-43-69.compute-1.amazonaws.com:22/DATABASE";
            var mongoEC2 = new MongoClient(connectionString);
            var server = mongoEC2.GetServer();
            var database = server.GetDatabase("DATABASE");
            var collection = database.GetCollection<MetadataTemplate>("COLLECTION");

            // Insert record into DB
            collection.Insert(metaUpload);
```

I am wondering if what's missing is that I'm not including the AWS Private Key (ppk) that I use in PuTTY. If this is the case, can anyone point me to how I can include this in the Mongo connection? As of now, the MongoClient(connectionString) is my only form of connection to Mongo or EC2. Is there a preliminary connection to the EC2 instance necessary that I'm missing?

Then again, I admit... I may be missing something else completely. All suggestions welcome.

UPDATE:

Below is the code I am using to create the SSH window.

```
            // Create a metadataObj for upload.
            MetadataTemplate metaUpload = createMetadataObj();

            // Create Secure SSH Connection
            var keyFile = new PrivateKeyFile(@"C:\Users\ahaque89\Documents\AmazonUploader\Resources\MYOPENKEY.ppk");
            var keyFiles = new[] { keyFile };
            var username = "bitnami";
            var methods = new List<AuthenticationMethod>();
            methods.Add(new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(username, keyFiles));
            var con = new ConnectionInfo(@"ec2-54-174-43-69.compute-1.amazonaws.com", 22, username, methods.ToArray());

            // Connect through SSH Client
            using (var client = new SshClient(con))
            {
                client.Connect();
                var cmd = client.RunCommand("ls");
                var output = cmd.Result;
                MessageBox.Show(output.ToString()); // Works successfully

                // Upload to MongoDB (ec2 server)
                var connectionString = "mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@bitnami@ec2-54-174-43-69.compute-1.amazonaws.com:22";
                var mongoEC2 = new MongoClient(connectionString);
                var server = mongoEC2.GetServer();
                var database = server.GetDatabase("DATABASE");
                var collection = database.GetCollection<MetadataTemplate>("COLLECTION");

                // Insert Record into DB
                collection.Insert(metaUpload); // Creates error
            }
```

Comment: As a further test, I've run the same code with a connectionString to a localhost DB and the insertion is completed successfully. So I know this must be a server connection issue.

Comment: As a further test.. I've tried wrapping the upload code inside of a (confirmed) working SshClient connection using SSH.Net. 

But again same error.

Comment: Is that the correct server name and port? bitnami@ec2-54-174-43-69.compute-1.amazonaws.com:22

Comment: @CraigWilson thanks Craig. And yes. Server name and port are correct. These come directly from PuTTY. 

http://www.evernote.com/l/ADqqO8_owIxGDoFpjgtvNrw19VcEsjbQguY/

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the remote server via an ssh tunnel? It looks like your connection string assumes a direct connection; you probably want to set up port forwarding via Putty instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this feature isn't yet supported in the MongoDB C# Driver. See response from Craig here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-csharp/b8PS4Qz9gjg